# LEFT JOIN ambiguous columns into one column in SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to `LEFT JOIN` two columns of a same nature, i.e. join `t2.Name` and `t3.Name` into a single column (dataproperty) `Name` in a T-SQL statement?

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.RowID,
       t2.name, 
       t3.Name 
  FROM MasterTable T1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable1 T2 
            ON T1.RowID = T2.ID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable2 T3 
            ON T1.RowID = T3.ID 
 WHERE t1.ID= " & ID & ";
```

...or do I have to load the tables into separate datasets and join them programatically (for each ... next) into a new dataset?

Regards,

Libor

Comment: You could concatenate the two fields into one, not forgetting to put the isnull clause. I think you can concatenate between two tables anyway...

Comment: Ah, I have never done that, but I see an example in an answer bellow, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on hat you mean by "join"  - here are a few possibilities:

If one is null and the other isn't, use `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t1.ID,
       t1.RowID,
       ISNULL(t2.name, t3.Name) Name
FROM MasterTable T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable1 T2 on T1.RowID = T2.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable2 T3 on T1.RowID = T3.ID
```

If you want to concatenate them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t1.ID,
       t1.RowID,
       t2.name + t3.Name Name
FROM MasterTable T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable1 T2 on T1.RowID = T2.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable2 T3 on T1.RowID = T3.ID
```

If you want two rows (a UNION):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t1.ID,
       t1.RowID,
       t2.Name
FROM MasterTable T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable1 T2 on T1.RowID = T2.ID 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t1.ID,
       t1.RowID,
       t3.Name
FROM MasterTable T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable2 T3 on T1.RowID = T3.ID
```

Note that DISTINCT is necessary because unless you can relate T2 and T3 you basically do a cross join (cartesian product) between T2 and T3 so you need to eliminate the duplicates that are created.

Comment: I don't see cross join in OP.

Comment: Great! In my case there is always one value, only in one of the tables (there are 5 tables to join!). I'll play around with ISNULL to handle dbnull values. Thank you very much

Comment: ...also there are no duplicates in my case, because the ID is unique across the 5 tables I am joining, meaning there is alway only one entry (somewhere in the 5 tables) matching the ID.

Comment: It wasn't as easy, but the working result is: CONCAT(IFNULL(t2.name,''),IFNULL(t3.Name,'')) AS Name. Sorry, this db is MySQL, not MS SQL (I'm working on both and made mistake in the original post).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.RowID,
       t2.name + t3.Name AS JoinedName
  FROM MasterTable T1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable1 T2 
            ON T1.RowID = T2.ID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable2 T3 
            ON T1.RowID = T3.ID 
 WHERE t1.ID= " & ID & ";
```